# sql query while i am excuting select query its loading for long time its not resulting its only loading

Tags: php, mysql, sql

its not resulting its loading

```
select p.*
from contacts p left outer join
     (select articleno, size, count(*) as cnt
      from bsd t
      group by articleno, size
     ) bc
     on p.articleno = bc.articleno and p.size = bc.size
where coalesce(cnt, 0) < (select count(*)
                          from contacts p2
                          where p2.articleno = p.articleno and
                                p2.size = p.size and
                                p2.id <= p.id
                         );
```

Comment: how about using EXPLAIN command and see if you can make some indexes on tables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The above query has lot of sub queries, because of which the processing is getting slow, and it will get worse if the volume of the data will increase, so it would be better you choose any other way to get the data, or you can use EXPLAIN to see where is the problem actually

Comment: if table have lessthan 50  rows  its displaying result if more than 50 rows  its just loading

Comment: That is what i was trying to say, as the volume of the data will increase the performance of the query will decrease, as the sub query always slow down the execution so please try to avoid using sub queries, where ever possible